# Create new tables for asp net core identity

Tags: asp.net-core, identity

When we apply the migration to an Asp Net Core Identity application, the system creates a set of basic Identity tables, where each table has its own columns. For example: the AspNetUsers table has its own set of columns, and it is possible to add new columns to that table.
Is it possible to remove columns?
If I don't want to use a particular column, is it possible to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

Ofcouse you can.Take the `AspNetUsers` table as an example.

First:Create a new `ApplicationUser`

```
public class ApplicationUser:IdentityUser
{
    //add a new colum
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    
    //remove a EmailConfirmed colum
    [NotMapped]
    public override bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
}
```

In your DbContext:

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

In your startup(Change `IdentityUser` to `ApplicationUser`).

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

In your `Views/Shared/_LoginPartial`,change to

```
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
```

Then `Migrate and generate database`.

Test Result:You can see successfully add `FullName` and remove the `EmailConfirmed` colums.

[image]

**For more details,you can see the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0#custom-user-data).**

**Note:What you need to pay attention to is that many of these columns contain built-in methods of Identity. If you delete some of these columns, it may result in abnormal usage of Identity, so you need to be careful when deleting these columns.**

Comment: Also, if you are using scaffolded identity page, make sure add all of them and change all over the pages where it was using IdentityUser model to applicationuser.